# Margin not working with fixed position navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sticky navigation bar.

So far I managed to create and style the bar just like I want it. The only problem is the margin.

I have that CSS code for the body:

```
body {
background: #202a2d;
padding: 1% 2% 0% 2%;
margin: 1% 2%;
}
```

and that for the navigation bar positioning:

```
.navigation_bar {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

I know that when the position is fixed, the child(nav bar) should ignore the parent's(body) margin.
But here the child inherits the left margin. On the other hand it ignores the right and bottom margin, so it ends up on top of the content below and filling all of the width to the right.

I found some other topics here and tried some of the suggested solutions but they didn't work.
So I tried:

- to set the margin in the navigation_bar but as expected in doesn't work
- to set the right and left but no luck, only one of them would work properly
- to set something like max-width: 1700px which isn't what I am looking since it doesn't work on all screens
- to set something like max-width: 93% which even though it works, I don't think that it's a proper solution and still it doesn't solve the bottom margin problem
- adding padding-bottom or margin-bottom in the nav for the overlapping problem, but it didn't work
- adding a wrapper around the nav bar and set the margin values in it, but again no luck

With position set to relative, everything looks good but it misses the point of being sticky.

Here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/Yanniskrz/4jjq9oqs/).

So, could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not applying the `margin-left`, it's applying the `padding` you've set on `body` as you haven't positionated your fixed nav bar with `top` and `left`.
I'm not sure if this is the effect you're intending (for the nav bar not to overlay your content initially) but the most common way is to set a `padding-top` on your body that is bigger than your fixed element's height, and I've also added top and left values on your fixed nav.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. I've changed the background to a light color so it can be easily appreciated.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5% 2% 0% 2%;
  margin: 1% 2%;
}

.site_heading {
  color: #3a8ccf;
}

.navigation_bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 1%;
  left: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  max-width: 96%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #47476b;
  color: #cc0066;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navigation_bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link .</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi
    vis ad, ad nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet.
    Eam posse ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum
    ea errem ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare,
    eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque.
    Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset. Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare
    duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent
    ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi vis ad, ad nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum
    choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet. Eam posse ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam
    nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum ea errem ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse
    cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare, eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat
    pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque. Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset.
    Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi vis ad, ad
    nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet. Eam posse
    ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum ea errem
    ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare,
    eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque.
    Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset. Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare
    duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent
    ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi vis ad, ad nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum
    choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet. Eam posse ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam
    nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum ea errem ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse
    cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare, eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat
    pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque. Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset.
    Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi
    vis ad, ad nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet.
    Eam posse ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum
    ea errem ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare,
    eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque.
    Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset. Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare
    duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent
    ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi vis ad, ad nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum
    choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet. Eam posse ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam
    nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum ea errem ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse
    cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare, eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat
    pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque. Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset.
    Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi vis ad, ad
    nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet. Eam posse
    ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum ea errem
    ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare,
    eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque.
    Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset. Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare
    duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut rebum indoctum corrumpit sed. Populo inermis atomorum te pri, vidisse commune in qui. Aliquid fierent
    ut sea, quo in quidam gubergren. Dicta prompta persecuti pro no. Graece deleniti constituam ut ius, quodsi salutandi vis ad, ad nisl nemore vituperata eum. Vis erat paulo scriptorem no. Nam ei falli putent, his elit malorum suscipit ne. Cum ne solum
    choro, ea sit paulo repudiare, aperiam delenit tibique ius te. Odio verear mel ne. Ut vim quis suscipit imperdiet. Eam posse ponderum expetendis te. Cum nonumy consetetur reprehendunt in. Fugit sonet theophrastus quo id. Habeo debitis ut sea, nam
    nulla legendos id. Eligendi epicurei molestiae sed ex, has nonumes corpora at. An meliore invenire aliquando mea. Cum ea errem ridens apeirian, nulla salutatus ei quo, postulant iudicabit iracundia an vix. Eu possit facete utroque usu. Iriure deseruisse
    cu mea. Esse integre definiebas an mei, prompta invidunt cu cum, vim in nonumy eligendi. Quo ne justo timeam accommodare, eu sea maiorum praesent. At eam accumsan repudiare. Vix ceteros consulatu et, est veri laboramus comprehensam ne. Quot oporteat
    pro ea, ea eum vide libris offendit. Nostrum percipit definitiones an quo, veri detracto quo ei. Cu mei docendi omnesque. Melius interesset est ut, per tincidunt vituperata cu. Quaeque admodum menandri ex pri, vix ex doming indoctum deterruisset.
    Id mei doctus explicari molestiae, dicant laudem est ne. Cum at facer paulo consul, at eros aliquam his. Mollis repudiare duo ex, id vel tollit accusam, mucius facilis corrumpit id mea. Altera consulatu vim no, suas natum nonumy sea te.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for answering. That was partially what I wanted to do. I wrapped the rest of the content (the paragraphs) into a div, which I styled with padding-top like you suggested and the bar doesn't overlap with it anymore. But I don't want to remove the margin. I want the body to have some empty space around it and not fill the full width. I want the navigation bar to have a 2% margin at both left and right.

Comment: I've just added `left:2%` and `right: 2%` as well as `max-width: 96%` so your fixed element has that margin you want. I've also left `top: 1%` in case the body top margin you sent should also be on your fixed element, but feel free to remove it otherwise. Does that work as you intended?

Comment: Gosh, now I feel stupid. I tried both left/right and max-width but never combined them together. I knew it would be something simple slipping my mind but didn't think it would be that simple. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.